# Grails Test mock RestTemplate.put method

Tags: grails, resttemplate

I am writing a **Junit using Grails** in which trying to mock a `restTemplate.put()` method. Somehow I am not getting any correct solution to do it. Any help would be great

Please note that I have already used `MockRestServiceServer` and it doesn't work.

Comment: `org.springframework.boot.test.TestRestTemplate` may be of use

Comment: How did you "use" that and in what way didn't it work? Please specify.